# How shall I validate minimum checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have several checkboxes in HTML and I want to make sure at least one is checked. And I would like use jQuery validator so that I need not manage the error message presentation business. Also, I want to do this before submitting the form. I want to validate it by clicking a button. My codes likes this:

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="label-class">
        <input type="checkbox" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="1" name="testing"></input>
    </label>
    <label class="label-class">
        <input type="checkbox" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="1" name="testing"></input>
    </label>
    <label class="label-class">
        <input type="checkbox" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="1" name="testing"></input>
    </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    var isOk = true;
    isOk = $("myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            testing: {
                minlength: 1
            }
        },
        message: {
            testing: "please select at least one item"
        }
    });
    return isOk; 
});
```

But this doesn't work well. How shall I implement this logic?

Comment: Is there a reason you using checkboxes vs radio buttons?

Comment: Did you try `$(":checked").length > 0`?

Comment: @Taplar: _“Is there a reason you using checkboxes vs radio buttons?”_ – radio buttons allow for _at most_ one choice, but he wants _at least_ one, so I think it can be implied that the user should be able to choose more than one option.

Comment: jQuery Validate is really meant for the whole form.  So you're probably best to use a custom solution if it's just for one checkbox group

Comment: Like Jquery's validator.element(), it can validate just one element in a form. But I don't know whether there is also a similar way to validate a group of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

try using------ "required: true"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! do you mean "testing: {required: true, minlenght: 1}"? I just tried according to your suggestion, but validation still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Submit your form if there is more than 1 checked checkbox element.

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="label-class">
    <input type="checkbox" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="1" name="testing"></input>
</label>
<label class="label-class">
    <input type="checkbox" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="1" name="testing"></input>
</label>
<label class="label-class">
    <input type="checkbox" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="1" name="testing"></input>
</label>
</div>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    return ($(":checked").length > 0);
});
```

Or:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    if ($(":checked").length > 0)
        // Submit your form here
    else
        // Display warning here
});
```

Comment: Hi, this works. But the shortcoming is this solution cannot make use of Jquery validator's feature like mark the checkbox as red and provide error message automatically.

Comment: Do you think the second solution will do it?

Comment: The second solution cannot make use of Jquery validator either. Jquery validator provide some features automatically, such as mark invalid element as red and present error messages around the element etc. Use the second solution, we can simulate jquery validator's behavior by ourselves, but not convenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is many mistakes you do in your code.
I have changed your code, change the names of checkboxes, add classes to them and other things.

```
<form id="myForm"><div class="control-group">
    <label class="label-class">
        <input type="checkbox" class="group1"  value="1" name="testing1"></input>
    </label>
    <label class="label-class">
        <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="1" name="testing2"></input>
    </label>
    <label class="label-class">
        <input type="checkbox" class="group1"  value="1" name="testing3"></input>
    </label>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And javascript:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            testing1: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".group1"]
            },
             testing2: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".group1"]
            },
             testing3: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".group1"]
            }
        },
        message: {
            testing1: "please select at least one item",
            testing2: "please select at least one item",
            testing3: "please select at least one item",
        }
     });

$("button").click(function(e) {

return $("#myForm").valid();

 });
```

**See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yqbkvs8/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks! is it possible that I just validate the checkbox, but not the whole form? Say can I create a customized rule in "$('button').click(function(e) {...});"?

Comment: One way I can think is change rule dynamically. This URL gives an introduction: http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.in/2008/09/starting-with-jquery-dynamically.html